# A word for a feeling of frustration at the unexpected ineptness of others

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to think of a word recently that would be used to describe the feeling of frustration or disappointment and annoyance or disgust at others directed especially towards their stupidity or incompetence, from the person's perspective, when the person was expecting more/for them to act differently or had high hopes in general. I'm trying to avoid the view of labeling the person as being overly arrogant thinking this way.

For instance,  *"What where they thinking?" the Hillary supporter exclaimed, filled with (**insert word here**)*

Or

*Indignant with his loss, the footballer sat in the changing room. Looking around, "I'm the only decent player on my team", he thought (**insert word here**)ly.*

Comment: _Despondent_ would be my reaction

Comment: "I don't believe in evil. I just believe in stupidity". -- Werner Herzog

Answer (score 5):

*Exasperation* captures the sense of feeling frustrated at the unexpected ineptness of others, especially when one fails repeatedly to get a purportedly obvious or simple point across.

Dictionary.com

> [*exasperation*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exasperation?s=t):
>   the state of being exasperated; irritation; extreme annoyance

Your example:

> "What where they thinking?" the Hillary supporter exclaimed, filled
>   with *exasperation*."

Answer (score 1):

[Disillusionment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disillusionment)(also check 'disenchanted')

> a feeling of disappointment resulting from the discovery that something is not as good as one believed it to be.

Disillusionment encompasses more of a feeling of being let down by someone than a feeling of disgust or annoyance.

[Sour(adj.)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sour)

> Noun:sourness
> Adverb: sourly
>
> Feeling or expressing resentment, disappointment, or anger.
>
> *‘he gave her a sour look’*
>
> *‘the meeting ended on a sour note’*

[Embitter](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/embitter)

> To embitter to make someone bitter, resentful, or angry. People are embittered by disappointing and unfair experiences.

Answer (score 1):

**Dismay** (n.)

> A feeling of unhappiness and disappointment:
>
> **Be filled with dismay** *Aid workers were said to have been filled with **dismay** by the appalling conditions that the refugees were living
> in.*
>
> **In/with dismay** *The fans watched in/with **dismay** as their team lost 42–11.*
>
> **To someone's dismay** *She discovered, to her **dismay**, that the paper was due a whole month earlier than she'd expected.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dismay)

---

> For example, Ann Temple argued in the *Daily Mail* in 1941, 'You've got it wrong, Mr Bevin', women would have 'responded
> magnificently' to appeals to volunteer if they had been organised
> properly, but 'in this war the voluntary system was doomed to failure
> from the very start by a stupidity, tactlessness and incompetence that
> made women draw back in **dismay**'.
> [Penny Summerfield; *Women Workers
> in the Second World War*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4xqwdJjRYtsC&pg=PA37&dq=dismay%20at%20the%20stupidity%20and%20incompetence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi03f320I2EAxUyk2oFHQzgCaoQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=dismay%20at%20the%20stupidity%20and%20incompetence&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

***[chagrin](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chagrin)***

> a feeling of vexation, marked by disappointment or humiliation.

*(dictionary.com)*

The *humiliation* part doesn't match, but the rest of it does.

Do use it as an adverb, you have to say "in chagrin."

Comment: I don't think that fits here.  I like 'exasperation' from below.

Comment: @user116032 - Yeah, *exasperated* is very good.

Answer (score -1):

Human

Typically we are witnessing the limits of our own independence and disappointed with intellectual compromises.
" NON POTESTIS FIGERE STULTUS "
( can't fix stupid )